# Captcha showing in comment form even with captcha off?

Tags: captcha

In my comment form I use {if captcha}...{/if} to only show the captcha if it is required. It is showing up for non-logged in users and not for myself, which makes sense.

The question is: How do I turn it off completely? I can not find any setting to turn of captcha's for comment forms in my 2.7.2 install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the {captcha} tags from the templates, or comment them out:

```
{!-- {captcha} etc.. --}
```

and / or turn the captcha off on each channel by going to the channel preference for the relevant channel: Admin > Channel Admin >  Channels > Edit Prefs

[Captcha docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/security/captchas.html)

Comment: The second part did it. I did not realize Captcha can be turned on/off per channel.

Follow-up question: if I were to remove the captcha from the form, I expect that would not work? I mean, without turning the 'captcha' setting to off, the system wants a captcha answer right?